# How to update markerClusterer count show on Clusterer using Gmap4Rails in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have filter marker based on type by below code

```
filters= ['office','home']

$.each(Gmaps.map.markers, function(i, marker) {
    if(filters.length < 1){
        Gmaps.map.showMarker(marker);
    }else if(filters.indexOf(marker.type) > -1){
        Gmaps.map.showMarker(marker);
    }else{
        Gmaps.map.hideMarker(marker);
    }
});
```

this code hide that marker but its not update Clusterer count on the map.

how to update Clusterer count on map

[image]

Comment: would be great you update to 2.x, where this is directly builtin

Comment: I update with 2.X but same issue

Comment: What's your 2.x code?

Comment: $.each(Gmaps.markers, function(i, marker) {
                if(filters.length < 1){
                    marker.show();
                }else if(filters.indexOf(marker.type) > -1){
                    marker.show();
                }else{
                    marker.hide();
                }
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with this code

```
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers_json = <%=raw @json.to_json %>;
        Gmaps.markers = _.map(markers_json, function(marker_json){
            marker = handler.addMarker(marker_json);
            _.extend(marker, marker_json);
            return marker;
        });
        handler.bounds.extendWith(Gmaps.markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
```

for manage event try with this code

```
    handler.clusterer.clear();
    $.each(Gmaps.markers, function(i, marker) {
         if(filters.length < 1){
               marker.show();
               handler.clusterer.addMarker(marker)
           }else if(filters.indexOf(marker.type) > -1){
              handler.clusterer.addMarker(marker);
              marker.show();
          }else{
              marker.hide();
              handler.clusterer.removeMarker(marker);
           }
    });
```